# ConversationScoped Flows in CDI

Tags: java, cdi, conversation-scope

I'm starting now with conversationScoped in CDI and i'm thinking about how can i configure the pages in the same conversation.

I would like to configure a XML to say: page1 and page2 should be in the same conversationScoped, page3 should be in new conversation.

Obs: In seam 2 i know that have pages.xml, but i'm not using seam.

Which is the better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use CDI conversation scope you should manually begin and finish conversation by calling `begin()` and `end()` methods respectively. This doesn't have xml configuration out of the box.

JSF flow scope implements what you want. Flow scope is not a kind of conversation scope but rather a custom scope that spreads over several pages. This can be configured by xml or from Java code. Take a look at this link for a comprehensive example: https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/